# Excel VBA: Parse English date from any OS region/locale

Tags: excel, vba, date, locale, region

I have a spreadsheet with a date selector. Day, month and year is selected in separate cells, like so:

[image]

Then I have some code that picks up the selected date, then checks if it's a real date (e.g. not 31st February), then checks if it's "greater or equal to" a preset date in cell A1. The format of the preset date in A1 doesn't matter, so long as it's in date format.

The function works absolutely fine until I change my OS region to, for example, Spain. Because very simply, CDate(blah) can parse "1 January 2016" when it's in UK/USA region, but in Spain region mode it is expecting to see Enero, febrero, marzo, abril, etc, instead of January, February, etc. This is the (Windows) setting I'm using to emulate other regions:

[image]

And this is a snippet of my code:

```
Sub getDate()
    'pick up date:
    theDay = Cells(13, 9).Value
    theMonth = Cells(13, 10).Value
    theYear = Cells(13, 11).Value

    theCurrentDate = theDay & " " & theMonth & " " & theYear

    'highlight bad date:
    If Not IsDate(theCurrentDate) Then
        Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If CDate(theCurrentDate) >= CDate(Cells(1, 1)) Then
        'do some stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

The 'highlight bad date' step is where the code glitches in a non-English region/locale setting... it will highlight the day cell. I figured this is a good enough way to spot bad dates such as 30th February, bearing in mind all three cells are data validated with lists.

It's important that the date is selected rather than typed in, and I'd like to maintain the visual format of DD-Month-YYYY, to transcend cultures (read: to force users to conform to a single format).

I've been trying to work out how to tell it to pretend the program locale is UK, for the code... or to tell it that the date it's picking up is in UK locale... I can't figure it, any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

---

EDIT1: I found a workaround for this problem. This works by converting the month name to a number and then using the DateSerial function to turn it into ... a serial date. The problem with this is, if you give it a date of 31st April (April has 30 days), then the date serial conversion will result in 1st May. So I had to make a routine that manually checks that it's a legitimate date (including leap years)... Here's the new code, again simplified although I've included error handling this time just to make it more complete):

```
Sub getDate()
    theErr = 0
    'pick up date:
    theDay = Cells(13, 9).Value
    theMonth = Cells(13, 10).Value
    theYear = Cells(13, 11).Value

    'Convert month name to number:
    If theMonth = "January" Then
        theMonth = 1
    ElseIf theMonth = "February" Then
        theMonth = 2
    ElseIf theMonth = "March" Then
        theMonth = 3
    ElseIf theMonth = "April" Then
        theMonth = 4
    ElseIf theMonth = "May" Then
        theMonth = 5
    ElseIf theMonth = "June" Then
        theMonth = 6
    ElseIf theMonth = "July" Then
        theMonth = 7
    ElseIf theMonth = "August" Then
        theMonth = 8
    ElseIf theMonth = "September" Then
        theMonth = 9
    ElseIf theMonth = "October" Then
        theMonth = 10
    ElseIf theMonth = "November" Then
        theMonth = 11
    ElseIf theMonth = "December" Then
        theMonth = 12
    End If

    'Check manually for bad dates:
    If InStr("2/4/6/9/11", CStr(theMonth)) Then 'a month with 30 or fewer days:
        If theMonth <> 1 Then 'January ("1") is found in 11, but January is OK, it has 31 days...
            If theDay = 31 Then
                Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                theErr = theErr + 1
            End If
            If InStr("2", CStr(theMonth)) Then 'February, with either 28 or 29 days:
                If theDay = 30 Then
                    Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                    theErr = theErr + 1
                ElseIf theDay = 29 Then
                    If theYear Mod 4 <> 0 Then 'not a leap year:
                        Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
                        theErr = theErr + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Give error message if date error picked up:
    If theErr <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please check your date", vbOKOnly, "getDate"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    theCurrentDate = DateSerial(theYear, theMonth, theDay)

    If CDate(theCurrentDate) >= CDate(Cells(1, 1)) Then
        'do some stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

It's a little lengthy.... but it does work, and now OS region doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off error handling and assign the created string date to a date variable.

You can then check to see if this caused an error; if it did, we know that the date used is not a real date.

This should work with all regions, as it is not relying on the OS language settings.

```
Sub getDate()

    Dim checkDate As Date

    'pick up date:
    theDay = Cells(13, 9).Value
    theMonth = Cells(13, 10).Value
    theYear = Cells(13, 11).Value

    theCurrentDate = theDay & " " & theMonth & " " & theYear

    On Error Resume Next
    checkDate = theCurrentDate

    'highlight bad date:
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    If CDate(theCurrentDate) >= CDate(Cells(1, 1)) Then
        'do some stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the input... sadly I can't get this to work, because again when changing OS region, setting checkDate to theCurrentDate results in a type mismatch... it still doesn't like the English month name, from Spanish OS. I've managed to come up with a workaround... which is a bit long for a comment so I'll post it by editing the original question...